# Variants of snake inclusive of fasting periods for Android devices

Tags: android, game, game-development, gamification

I am looking for a cute variation of the famous game "snake", the one where there is a snake that grows eating apples that appear as though randomly on the screen and the game ends if the snake eats itself or if it touches the edge of the screen, or grows too long and runs over itself.

The variant has a mechanism where a timed fasting interval is activated by some event triggered by some being in the game. When the fasting interval is activated, eating any apple would end the game, or else the apples turn momentarily poisonous or infected and eating three of them ends the game. The snake must then, in this case, work towards towards getting themselves from the poison, in some game-defined way. The timing integral can be fixed or variable, depending on how the game wants to be designed.

I am looking for this variant app to run on my Android device, of at all possible.

Thanks.